# Java Strategy Min-Max

Tags: java, strategy-pattern

Learning Java on hyperskill. Get stuck on strategy topic. Community there is non responsive and I do not understand why I am not getting correct result. Please help.
I assume that I am not getting what this part actually mean :"If the array is empty, the Finder should return Integer.MAX_VALUE in case of finding the min value and Integer.MIN_VALUE in case of finding the max value."

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Finder {

    private FindingStrategy strategy;

    public Finder(FindingStrategy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    /**
     * It performs the search algorithm according to the given strategy
     */
    public int find(int[] numbers) {
       return this.strategy.getResult(numbers);
    }
}

interface FindingStrategy {

    /**
     * Returns search result
     */
    int getResult(int[] numbers);

}

class MaxFindingStrategy implements FindingStrategy {
    @Override
    public int getResult(int[] numbers) {
        if (numbers.length > 0 ){
            Arrays.sort(numbers);
            return numbers[0];
        } else {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

    }
}

class MinFindingStrategy implements FindingStrategy {
    @Override
    public int getResult(int[] numbers) {
        if (numbers.length > 1 ){
            Arrays.sort(numbers);
            return numbers[numbers.length-1];
        } else {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;  
        }
    }
}

/* Do not change code below */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        final String[] elements = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        int[] numbers = null;

        if (elements[0].equals("EMPTY")) {
            numbers = new int[0];   
        } else {
            numbers = new int[elements.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(elements[i]);
            }
        }

        final String type = scanner.nextLine();

        Finder finder = null;

        switch (type) {
            case "MIN":
                finder = new Finder(new MinFindingStrategy());
                break;
            case "MAX":
                finder = new Finder(new MaxFindingStrategy());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (finder == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unknown strategy type passed. Please, write to the author of the problem.");
        }

        System.out.println(finder.find(numbers));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also a hint as to how to implement it. Your version both modifies the input array (considered poor practice) and takes O(n log n) time; you can implement a version in O(n) that has the required characteristic naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use streams for this job:

```
Arrays.stream(numbers).min().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

Arrays.stream(numbers).max().orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

Since with this stream you do not have to check `numbers.length` it also solves your issue of checking `numbers.length > 1` instead of `numbers.length > 0`.

Comment: I didn' get to learn streams yet, but Thank you! that actually let me pass the task.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that when no input is available you need to either return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` OR `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. If the request is to find the minimum value from the input but the input is empty, you return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and alternatively if the input is empty and max is requested you return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Your specific problem is because of this;

```java
if (numbers.length > 1 ){
```

You need to check if length > 0, not 1.

Comment: It was 0 previously, was trying multiple things there. Even with change to 0 still does not let me pass that task.